# Query to update array elements in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
I have a mongo document like this
{
"_id" : "2213",
"userId" : "99872",
"enterpriseId" : 13,
"courses" : [
 {
  "stateName" : "test program345",
  "courseId" : "456",
  "courseName" : "testCourse",
  "duration" : 1,
  "lag" : 0,
  "courseType" : "3",
  "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2019-07-02T10:16:22.000+05:30"),
  "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2019-07-02T10:16:22.000+05:30"),
  "transitionType" : "onComplete"
 },
 {
  "stateName" : "test program3455",
  "courseId" : "4",
  "courseName" : "testCourse",
  "duration" : 1,
  "lag" : 0,
  "courseType" : "2",
  "transitionType" : "onComplete",
  "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2019-07-08T17:07:13.479+05:30"),
  "courseProgress" : 100
 }
],
"userStatus" : 1,
"modified" : ISODate("2019-07-02T10:16:22.634+05:30"),
"created" : ISODate("2019-07-02T10:16:22.634+05:30"),
"completionStatus" : "IP"
}

I want to Update only those document where courseId is 4 and courseProgress is not exits and completionStatus is not equal to F.
```

I have made this query but still updated the document even courseProgress is exists on second index of array

```
db.table.update({
    'courses.courseId':'4',
    'completionStatus':{$ne:'F'},
    'courses':{$elemMatch:{'courseProgress':{$exists:false}}},
    'enterpriseId':13},
    {$set : {'courses.$.courseId' : '45','courses.$.courseName':'testCourse'}},{multi:true}
)
```

Still this query is updated the field even though courseProgress is exists on array's second index.As i am new to mongodb,Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`$` only updates the first element it matches in the array. To update all the matched elements of the array you need to use `$[]`.

Try this :

```
db.table.update({
    'courses.courseId':'4',
    'completionStatus':{$ne:'F'},
    'courses':{$elemMatch:{'courseProgress':{$exists:false}}},
    'enterpriseId':13},
    {$set : {'courses.$[].courseId' : '45','courses.$[].courseName':'testCourse'}},{multi:true}
)
```

For detailed information, please read [$[] Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

Comment: I am using mongodb 3.4 ,$[] is available in version 3.6

Comment: If you dont have version 3.6 or higher, you need to do a find(), update the array manually and save it.